# Does JQuery or JavaScript have a next statement/function to skip to the next iteration of a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have this code, where I would like that `next` skips to next iteration.

```
$.each(result, function(key, value) {

    if (value.type == "individuel") {
    cform["IN"] = "checked";
    } else if (value.type == "course") {
    cform["CO"] = "checked";
    } else {

    next;

    }

    cform["ID"]     = key;
    cform["title"]  = value.title;

    $('#template').tmpl(cform).appendTo('#content');
});
```

But `next` apparently means something different from what I would expect.

It seams to me that `next` exits the `$.each` rather than skipping the current key/value.

Does there exist a way to do `next` like I would expect?

Comment: `next` is not a keyword or reserved word in Javascript, so unless it was defined somewhere as a variable, putting `next` in your code should throw a `ReferenceError`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to the nature of jQuery, there is no way to state a "next" in the function body. The inner function does not *know* that it is being executed in a loop and can therefore not influence this fact.

But you can return early, which has the same effect:

```
$.each(result, function(key, value) {
  if (value.type == "individuel") {
    cform["IN"] = "checked";
  } else if (value.type == "course") {
    cform["CO"] = "checked";
  } else {
    return true;
  } 

  cform["ID"]     = key;
  cform["title"]  = value.title;
  $('#template').tmpl(cform).appendTo('#content');
});
```

I find this more stylish:

```
$.each(result, function(key, value) {
  switch (value.type) {
    case "individuel": cform["IN"] = "checked"; break;
    case "course":     cform["CO"] = "checked"; break; 
    default: return true;
  }

  cform["ID"]     = key;
  cform["title"]  = value.title;
  $('#template').tmpl(cform).appendTo('#content');
});
```

Comment: Be wary that `return false` breaks the entire loop and short circuits it.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike other constructs, such as `for..in` and `while`, `$.each` is not a language construct. With those constructs, you can use `continue` to skip the current element and `break` to leave the loop.  Since `$.each` takes a callback function, you need to use the callback's `return` value to affect what happens next.

Return `true` to continue to the next item; return `false` to break the loop.

In this case, you should use `return true`:

```
else {
   return true; // skip to next element
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**return true;**

From the docs:

> We can break the $.each() loop at a
>   particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false.
>   Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it
>   will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

[jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 1):

Using the if statement makes the next unnecessary. Simply do whatever you want in the if and ignore the else. The iteration moves on automatically.

Comment: Won't I then have the same code twice? Ie. the last 3 lines of code would be in each `if`-statement. This is a simplified example. There is about 20 lines of code more.

Comment: You will have to configure your if statement to suit your purposes. Under what condition do you need to run the 20 lines of code? Then set that condition and run them, then break down to the more specific cases.

Answer (score -1):

Use `continue;` to skip to the next iteration in a loop.

Edit: Yep, sorry about that I swear I saw a loop in there :( You can "continue" in jQuery's each() by returning a non-false value, will a return work for your case?

Comment: I edited my answer.. @Raynos, does that mean that I can't use continue in a `while` :)